# Run time based on spark web UI / history server

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running simple pyspark job which reads input data from cloud storage, filters, un-nestes nested json columns and writes to destination bucket.

The job took ~50min to complete (excluding cluster boot time). Looking at spark web UI, jobs tab, spark has created 4 jobs. The overall duration of all 4 jobs comes to ~40 min. Trying to understand, why spark history server is not showing remaining 10mins? Is it fair to expect overall time of all jobs to be equal to total runtime of spark application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application does more than just running Spark jobs. Spark jobs are operations that you do on your distributed data (RDDs, DataFrames or Datasets). But sometimes, something has to happen on the driver that is not a distributed calculation. A very simple example here:

```py
import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
time.sleep(20)

df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("./small_csv.csv")

time.sleep(20)
df.withColumn("extraCol", lit("someExtra")).write.mode("overwrite").csv("output.csv")
```

The corresponding history server logs look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the sum of all jobs is 0.5s, but the total uptime is 44s. This is because I've added two `time.sleep(20)` lines that artificially make the application wait.

So what are some realistic examples of non-distributed calculations that might take significant time? For example:

- listing files on an object store when doing `spark.read.parquet("someDir/*")`
- removing a file programmatically
- waiting for some connection to happen
- doing a heavy calculation on the driver after doing `df.collect()`
- ...